# SVG.js doesn't wire its svg element up properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, svg.js

I have an svg element in my HTML code: 
`<svg id="drawingPad"></svg>`

Then, in my script I have this call: 
`var drawingPad = SVG('drawingPad').size('100%', '100%').fixSubPixelOffset()`

Logging with `console.log(drawingPad)` and `console.log($document[0].getElementById('drawingPad'))` results in

```
SVG.Doc.SVG.invent.create {parent: svg#drawingPad, _stroke: "#000000", trans: Object, node: svg#drawingPad, type: "svg"…}
```

and

```
<svg id="drawingPad"></svg>
```

showing that SVG.js seems to correctly create its SVG.Doc element, but it doesn't seem to affect the HTML / DOM.

This happens whenever* I get to the page containing my SVG element by `$location.path('/editor')`. When I directly go there or when I reload, everything works correctly.

*Actually, I need to visit pages in between to re-trigger it. If I just go back and click the link again, it works, too!

So I'm stumped. Does anyone here have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You are creating an empty SVG element which by default has no color and no border. What are you expecting to see? http://duane.freeshell.net/code/SVG_Tutorial/html_primitives.png

Comment: This is a two year old thread, but anyway. An editor in the browser was the goal. It would load an image as background and let you annotate / paint onto the image. SVG.js didn't initialize the SVG, so stuff just didn't work. You'd see the image, but be unable to interact.

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never used SVG.js specifically, could be that Angular might not be "aware" of SVG.js in some cases. Try wrapping your SVG rendering function in a `$timeout()`

```
$timeout(function(){
   //..code goes here 
});
```

Comment: So I should do
`$timeout(function(){
  drawingPad = SVG('drawingPad').size('100%', '100%').fixSubPixelOffset()
});`
? Just to to make sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: I've now built this, and it seems to work (needs more testing) but I don't understand why.

What do you mean by "aware"?
Why would a 1s delay even seemingly fix my problem?

If you can help me understand, that would be greatly appreciated, otherwise just thanks for helping me out!

Comment: So you should accept the answer ;)  An Angular app is a self-contained world, that uses its own special processes to render DOM elements, such as the digest cycle and `$apply()` methods. Many times you cannot just throw in a jquery plugin or other scripts without taking special steps to introduce it to the Angular digest cycle, such as making a custom directive and provider. The `$timeout() ` method is a wrapper around setTimeout which implicitly calls $scope.$apply, meaning it runs outside of the angular lifecycle, but kickstarts the angular lifecycle itself.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, that makes some sense, so thanks a lot again. Do you have any idea why it would work sometimes, though? And why explicitly calling $scope.$apply didn't help?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but could be some race condition where some script was loading before another, if you are using cdn sources. Or something totally different :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to unaccept, because it turns out that this doesn't really fix it after all. It's much better than before, but not good enough.

Also, we're not using CDN sources.